# Preenchimento de dois inputs igual

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom eu estou com o seguinte problema, tenho dois inputs :

```
Desconto<input type="text" name="desconto" id="desconto" style="width: 100px" >
```

e

```
Observação<input readonly="true" type="text" name="obs" id="obs" style="width: 400px; height: 30px" >
```

eu gostaria que assim que eu escrevesse algo no primeiro input(desconto)automaticamente a mesma coisa fosse preenchida no segundo input

Comment: Já tentaste algum código?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim, com JavaScript nativo:

```
var desconto = document.getElementById('desconto');
var obs = document.getElementById('obs');

desconto.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    obs.value = this.value;
});
```

Assim usas o evento `keyup` para correr uma função que atribui a `#obs` o valor do elemento que disparou o evento, ie o `#desconto`

#### exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/w0gvo7yv/

Answer (score 4):

Você deve atribuir um evento ao txt que será utilizado para digitar. Veja o exemplo que fiz utilizando o `keyup`.

```js
$('#txtUm').on('keyup', function () {
  $('#txtDois').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtUm" />
<input type="text" id="txtDois" />
```